# Add a "global" keystroke handler to Linux/X-Windows system

Tags: linux, hotkeys, window-managers

I would like to add a keystroke handler to my Linux system (actually Ubuntu Linux, but pointers to X11 generally will be helpful).

The goal is simple enough in principle, I have a "drawing" program that lets me write on a transparent panel. I want to have a single keystroke that toggles this from the top to the bottom (and back again) of the window stack.

I guess I need to interact with the window manager, but that's where my ideas run out. What research directions can I try next?

Comment: If you are willing to work with the window manager then registering a binding with it to do this is likely the easiest approach. If you aren't interested in doing that (because you want something more agnostic) then you might be able to do a raw grab from your program itself but that may or may not work robustly (and is much more likely to run afoul of focus stealing prevention measures in many modern window managers).

Comment: Have you considered looking at one of the many programs with window independent hotkeys to see how they do it?

Comment: Elan, yes, that's kinda where I was thinking I'd have to go, though I'm not sure where to start. I guess #1 is find out what WM is even in use!

"other guy" hmm, didn't know there were any that did this. Can you give an example? The only things that I'm aware of are things like the screen capture program, but that's not the program grabbing it, it's somehow built into the WM, or ... something. There's a tool for configuring it, but it doesn't _seem_  to help with what I need (at least I haven't found any description of it that helps me know how)